# How to find position of elements with same class in selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am making a simple program that opens up Google Keep and makes a new list. The problem I am running into is that list items all have the same class in html, therefore when the program runs, it does not create a new item on the list, instead types it all as one item.

I have tried to use xpath, but truth be told I have a hard time understanding the concept and it was also a far-fetched reach to try and fix the problem.

Here is the code for that specific part of the program:

```py
listItem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.notranslate.IZ65Hb-YPqjbf.fmcmS-x3Eknd.CmABtb-YPqjbf')


listItem.send_keys('COM 305 - DB (Initial Post)')
listItem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
listItem.send_keys('COM 305 - DB (Replies)')
listItem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
listItem.send_keys('PHI 315 - DB (Initial Post)')
listItem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

The program should create a new list item instead of putting it all onto one line. I think from the documentation I understand that the find_element function finds the first available from the HTML, so I'm assuming that's why it keeps putting it into one item.

Is there a way to make them separate?

Comment: Every `find_element_` method has `find_elements_` counterpart that will return a list of webelements.

Comment: Just for fun, add a sleep (of 1-5 seconds) after the enter key. See if that gives you what you want. If it does, than you can add in some waits (better than sleeps). If it doesn't than the enter key isn't triggering the javascript action to create a new entry, so you'll need to fire that event progrmatically or reconsider your approach.

Comment: Also your find element to find the "input" box is fine. You don't need find elementS in this case. Your methodology is correct, though that class locator is going to be fragile.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried using a sleep, I probably should have mentioned that. Guess I'll be researching javascript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody is curious, I did find the solution. I had to make it all one automated action from the listItem driver. Here is the code that worked:

```py
listItem.send_keys('COM 305 - DB (Initial Post)', Keys.ENTER, 
    'COM 305 - DB (Replies)', Keys.ENTER, 
    'PHI 315 - DB (Initial Post)', Keys.ENTER, 
    'PHI 315 - DB (Replies)', Keys.ENTER, 
    'SEC 235 - DB (Initial Post)', Keys.ENTER, 
    'SEC 235 - DB (Replies)')
```

I think anytime the driver was called, it started at the top of the list, where it could find the first class found, therefore always printing on the first line. 
Dunno if anybody cares, but thought I'd post it.